# Checking if any radio groups do not have a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to throw an alert if a user attempts to submit a form without providing a selection for any of the radio groups. The form is dynamic as are the names of the radio inputs.

I have come up with the following solution:

```
$("input:radio").each(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  if($("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked").length == 0) {
    incomplete = true;
  }
});
```

However I am receiving the following console error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:radio[name=response_text[11898]]
```

What is syntactically invalid here?

Edit: HTML added as requested

```
<div class='form-group'>
  <label for='11899'>2. The earth is flat</label>
    <ol class='answers' id='11899' tabindex='2'>
        <li class='answer'>
            <input type='radio' name='response_text[11899]' value='766' id='766'>
      <label for='766' class='answer-text'>True</label>
     </li>
     <li class='answer'>
          <input type='radio' name='response_text[11899]' value='767' id='767'>
          <label for='767' class='answer-text'>False</label>
     </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add your html

Comment: try adding quotes around `name` like this `$("input:radio[name='"+name+"']:checked")` or add your html

Comment: Please don’t remove relevant code from your question. Further, please look at what the [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element is for, and what it’s `for` attribute should be.

Comment: only downside to your solution is you are checking the groups over and over again

Comment: @DavidThomas I am using the <label> element as described by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label. What do you think needs to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rare missing quotes around the `name`

change

```
$("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked")
```

to

```
$("input:radio[name='"+name+"']:checked")
```

Your full code should look like this

```
$("input:radio").each(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  if($("input:radio[name='"+name+"']:checked").length == 0) {
    incomplete = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that was it